# Magento 2 : custom image role apply in multiple images

Tags: product-images, custom-attributes, magento2.2.4

I created one custom image role from admin side. It's working perfect.

But, I want to set that custom image role in multlple images. I read this [git](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1548) issue but I didn't found any source to apply this functionality.

How can I apply this ?

Comment: Did you get solution of this?

Comment: did you get any solution???